# MongoDB count total of three fields

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am a beginner in MongoDB. I have 20 million documents in a MongoDB collection. Example of a single document:

[image]

I want to get the total tweet count, friends count and followers count of each user_screen_name along with each user_screen_name's account creation year.

I tried this:

```
user_details_pipeline = [{
    "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "user_mentions": 1,
        "user_followers_count": 1,
        "user_friends_count": 1,
        "user_account_creation": 1
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": "$user_mentions"
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$user_mentions.screen_name",
        "count": {
            "$sum": 1
        }
    }
}, {
    "$sort": {
        "count": -1
    }
}
]
```

But this does not querying the count of tweets, followers, friends and account creation date, only how many times a user is being mentioned. Can anyone please help?

Example of one output:

```
{"user_screen_name": "BorisJohnson", "user_followers_count": 1000000, "user_friends_count": 50, "total_tweets": 50000, "user_account_creation": 2012}
```

Comment: Could you add an example of what you would like to see as the output (not a screenshot please).

Comment: The image for the example collection is down, can you add code?

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to use `$group` aggregation here.

```
aggregate([
    { $group: {
        _id: "$user_screen_name",
        user_followers_count: { $sum: "$user_followers_count" },
        user_friends_count: { $sum: "$user_friends_count" },
        total_tweets: { $sum: "$total_tweets" },
        user_account_creation: { $first: "$user_account_creation" }
    }}
])
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Dates are not stored as ISODate(). Is there any other way?

Comment: Could you paste your document replacing your image

Answer (score 1):

If your date is not a date type (it really should be though!), you can use the following aggregate query using [$substr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) (to slice out the year) and [$min](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/index.html) (to get the earliest year)

```
result = db.mycollection.aggregate([
    {'$group': {
        '_id': '$user_screen_name',
        'user_followers_count': {'$sum': '$user_followers_count'},
        'user_friends_count': {'$sum': '$user_friends_count'},
        'total_tweets': {'$sum': '$user_tweets_count'},
        'user_account_creation': {'$min': {'$substr': ['$user_account_creation', 26, 4]}}
    }},
    {'$project': {
        '_id': 0,
        'user_screen_name': '$_id',
        'user_followers_count': 1,
        'user_friends_count': 1,
        'total_tweets': 1,
        'user_account_creation': 1
    }}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using aggregation. You are simply projecting the desired fields, but aggregation provides the `$year` operator (and others) to return the desired component from a date. You should ensure that the dates have been stored as `ISODate()`.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        "$project" : {
            "_id": 0,
            "user_screen_name": 1,
            "user_followers_count": 1,
            "user_friends_count": 1, 
            "total_tweets": 1,
            "user_account_creation": { 
                "$year" : "$user_account_creation"
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

If you are not using `ISODate()`, you can use the `$dateFromString` operator with format specifies to get an `ISODate()` then use that as needed.

```
{
    "$dateFromString": {
        "dateString": "06-15-2018",
         "format": "%m-%d-%Y"
    }
}
```

However, the format specifiers listed in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) only work with numerical components and not words (like “Thurs” or “Jan”).

Comment: Thank you for the response. Dates are not stored as ISODate(). Is there any other way?

Comment: @shay I found some info on `$dateFromString` but it doesn’t seem to work with words for days and months. I’m wondering if you could extract just the year from your string?